# Stretch spacing after the last row of a tasks environment

Tags: tasks

I am making an exam using the tasks package, and I would like to have each item/row to have an equal amount of space under it. Typically I would do this with a bunch of `\vfill` thrown around, but the tasks environment has the helpful `after-item-skip` option that, when set to `after-item-skip=\fill`, does exactly what I want, *except* in the last row. There is also the option `after-skip`, but setting that to `\fill` doesn't seem to do anything. I can put specific measurements as values for `after-skip` and it will work as expected, but I would rather not have to eyeball it on each page. How can I get a stretchy vertical space after a tasks environment?

Here is some sample code and its output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
    A sample problem:
    \begin{tasks}[after-item-skip=\fill,after-skip=\fill] (2)
        \task Task 1
        \task Task 2
        \task Task 3
        \task Task 4
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Not sure what was wrong with the default layout of tasks environment. If you remove `[after-item-skip=\fill,after-skip=\fill]` do you obtain the desired result?

Comment: @LuisTurcio Without those options, the items stack on top of one another with minimal spacing. I'd like to have the environment stretch over the whole page with equal distribution of space to each "row".